# Why is the alternating group called "alternating"?

Tags: group-theory, terminology

The title says it all: Why is the alternating group called alternating? What is being alternated that is not being alternated by any permutation?

Comment: See [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74208/meaning-of-alternating-group).

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/74208/meaning-of-alternating-group

Comment: Yes, I can tell.